# QTableView Scrolling by dragging/grabbing the table itself

Tags: qt, qtableview

How do you make a QtableView dragable in terms of scrolling it up and down. Not changing its position. Like when you use a hand tool in a pdf reader to scroll the pages.

Answer (score 2):

The `QScroller` class enables kinetic scrolling for any scrolling widget or graphics item.

```
QScroller *scroller = QScroller::scroller(ui->tableView);
ui->tableView->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
ui->tableViews->setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
```

You might want to disable overshoot policy of scroller...

```
QScrollerProperties properties = QScroller::scroller(scroller)->scrollerProperties();
QVariant overshootPolicy = QVariant::fromValue<QScrollerProperties::OvershootPolicy>(QScrollerProperties::OvershootAlwaysOff);
properties.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::VerticalOvershootPolicy, overshootPolicy);
scroller->setScrollerProperties(properties);
properties.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::HorizontalOvershootPolicy, overshootPolicy);
scroller->setScrollerProperties(properties);
//Scrolling Gesture
scroller->grabGesture(ui->tableView,QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
```

You can replace `LeftMouseButtonGesture` with `TouchGesture` for touchscreens.